# How to set default values for user attributes in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is there a way to set default values for custom user attributes in AWS-COGNITO at registration? I have a custom field "custom:status" and I'd like it to have a default value of "NOT_VALIDATED". I don't want the value to come from the client since the client might put "VALIDATED" instead and have extra permissions.

I have tried to set my status field in the pre signup lambda function but the value is ignored.

Comment: It's 2023 and this feature is still unavailable on Cognito (without trigger workarounds). Adding this comment to record that having the ability to specify a default value for a custom attribute would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from a lambda trigger. In that case you don't have to update the attributes yourself but you can call adminUpdateUserAttributes on the user to update the attribute.

Comment: It's not possible since user doesn't even exist.

Comment: @machin if `Pre sign-up trigger` is not working, you can use `Post confirmation trigger` to update the value immediately after the user has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to let it come from the client, but also send the value in the clientMetadata field of the request but encrypted. So that when it hits your pre-signup lambda you can make sure that the what the client passed is the same as the decrypted clientMetadata. If it is not just reject the registration as they tampered with the value.